# Get pouchdb database info

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

So I am trying to get the length of a pouchdb database.
I am following their api reference to get the length (https://pouchdb.com/api.html#database_information).
Basically, I have a function which does stuff at the end of that function I want to store the length of the database into a variable.

```
const db_len_func = this.db.info().then(result => {
  return result['doc_count']
})

const db_len = async() =>{
  this.nextNodeIndex = await db_len_func
}
```

But when I run this function the `this.nextNodeIndex` is not getting updated. I want to use this variable inside another function.
I am new to promise functions, so any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean `await db_len_func()` (note the parenthesis).  Note `db_len_func` is evaluating to the promise returned by the call to `this.db.info()` (yes that is a function call not a declaration). Also, be consistent with patterns - either stick with Promises or async await.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem with pouchDB rather some confusion about Promises and Async/Await.  Either pattern is fine, however choose one - async/await is "modern" - and stick to it; mixing patterns may eventually result in confusing code.

A few problems with the code posted. First, `db_len_func`

```
const db_len_func = this.db.info().then(result => {
  return result['doc_count']
})
```

Is *not* a function, it is a Promise returned by the invocation of `this.db.info()`.

As for `db_len`

```
const db_len = async() =>{
  this.nextNodeIndex = await db_len_func
}
```

When `db_len` is invoked it assigns `this.nextNodeIndex` to the value of `db_len_func` which may either be undefined or a promise depending on call order and timing.  For what it's worth, variable naming comes into play here. the intention would seem to be `await db_len_func()`, however it is possible to `await` a Promise.

This is likely towards your solution.

```
const db_len_func = async () => { 
   let info = await this.db.info();
   return info['doc_count'];
})

const db_len = async() => {
  this.nextNodeIndex = await db_len_func();
}

// some where, some place, some time....

db_len();
```

Assuming `this` is the same object, I would simply do

```
const updateDocCount = async() => {
   this.nextNodeIndex = await this.db.info().doc_count;
}
```

`nextNodeIndex` seems like a mysterious name for what is `doc_count` IMO.

If going with Promises, I highly recommend reading this blog by Nolan Lawson titled [We have a problem with promises](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html).